# I am not quite able to comprehend the proof of the Russell's paradox given in naive set theory by Halmos

Tags: set-theory

Apologies for my immodesty if this sounds too "naive" but I am a beginner in math(16) and found set theory a good way to start my mathematical pursuit.

So I was studying naive set theory by Paul R Halmos and came across a hurdle in chap 2 .

In the proof of the Russel's paradox Halmos asserts an arbitrary set $A$ and then follows it by "whatever the set $A$ may be , if $\lbrace B = {x∈A:x∉x}\rbrace$ then , for all $y, y ∈ B$ if and only if ($y∈A$ and $y∉y$)"

The author then proceeds to proof that $B ∉ A$. Now the part of the proof which I  couldn't quite comprehend is this - "Indeed if $B∈A$ then either $B∈B$ also or else $B∉B$ " . How exactly did he reach this conclusion?

To give some  background I looked up a video on YouTube on the topic by up and atom and found the video
quite helpful. I understood the barber paradox and how a set containing all sets doesn't exist .
I just found the above part of the technical proof of the paradox difficult to understand.
Please help
THANKS

Comment: That $B\in B$ or $B\not\in B$ is just an instance of the law of the excluded middle: for *any* property whatsoever, either $B$ has that property or it doesn't - now just take the property "is an element of itself." (Note that the "If $B\in A$" is not needed for this part!)

Comment: @Noah Schweber thanks for clearing my silly diffculty  . I thought it was somehow related to B belonging to A